# Has Wolverine Ever Been Submerged?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

Has Logan ever been submerged in water, lava, acid or anything else for a period of time? If so did he remain operational during that time, or did he pass out until his skeleton was removed? Question is for all universes.

Comment: Why would his skeleton be removed by him being submerged in water?!

Comment: Under water is more of a question of breathing and operation. Something like lava or avoid I would assume takes him to the bone. Saw a picture of him surviving a blast that took him to the bone, and guess he survived a nuclear blast. So that is the reason for the skeleton question on those types of liquid like lava and acid.

Comment: For the liquids like acid, if he kept regenerating he could eventually dilute the liquid then regenerate, but then it becomes the question again if he is operational under liquid.

Comment: Can apply the question up to Saber tooth or anyone else with same powers too.

Comment: While this question is for all universes, the first three X-Men movies fractured their own canon is several places and also didn't cover the circumstances brought up in the question. I would be surprised to find there isn't a clear answer to this (or, perhaps several), but I would stick to the comics due to there breadth and consistency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of X-Men: Days of Future Past, Wolverine is lifted up from the bottom of the river (most likely Potomac because it's in DC) on a boat. It's unclear how long he's been in the water, but he's unconscious and has been probably under the surface for at least some time. The crew is guided by Col. Stryker, likely for his experiment to convert his skeleton to adamantium. I've never read the comics. But it's definitely in the movie canon.

Comment: "Guided by Colonel Stryker. " Indeed?

Comment: Not to mention that in the X-Men and X-2 movies timeline he was submerged in a water tank to have the adamantium bonded to his skeleton